# Which Is better : Multi databases or single database

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have about `1.63 GB` text information in 11 databases.

these databases information is not realated to each other.
my application run from DVD i have some problem for first connection to each database
its take some moment to open connection to each database.
I have a question: which is better?
1-collect all tables in a single database increase my application speed?
I created my databases with SQLCE 3.5 and i'm using entity framework.

Comment: So evidently this is a read-only database?

Comment: @Kirk Woll : yes it's read-only.

Comment: Do both and measure which performs better? (Hint: if your answer is "that'll take too much time!" then it doesn't matter which approach you choose)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question really doesn't provide enough good context to answer properly, but if the initial connection latency is the problem then naturally reducing the number of outbound connections will improve performance. How a single database affects performance and scalability is impossible to know given the lack of context.

Comment: exactly initial connection latency for each database take some moment.if i collect all database in a single one i just have one  initial connection?is it true?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the number of databases, generally you should be pooling connections...

Pooling leaves a set of connections already established and ready to use with no overhead

Comment: True, but the question is explicitly focused on the first connection.